# Combine 2 Serialized json string

Tags: c#, .net, jsonserializer, hubspot

Here is how I'm serializing dictionary to JSON:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictFormValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> hsContext = new Dictionary<string, string>();

dictFormValues.Add("firstname", "Name");
dictFormValues.Add("lastname", "LastName");
dictFormValues.Add("email", "Email");

hsContext.Add("ipAddress", "ip");
hsContext.Add("pageUrl", "url");
hsContext.Add("pageName", "Title");

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

string strFormContentJSON = json.Serialize(dictFormValues); //First JSON
string strHubSpotContextJSON = json.Serialize(hsContext); //Second JSON
```

How can I combine those 2 together where they will look like below:

```
var data = {
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "firstname",
      "value": "Name"
    },
    {
      "name": "lastname",
      "value": "LastName"
    },
    {
      "name": "email",
      "value": "Email"
    }        
  ],
  "context": {
    "ipAddress": "ip",
    "pageUri": "url",
    "pageName": "Title"
  }
}
```

I tried something like this but I don't know if this is even right:

```
string strPostData = "";

strPostData = json.Serialize(new { OneDetails = strFormContentJSON, TwoDetails = strHubSpotContextJSON });
```

Comment: You should avoid the JavaScriptSerializer if at all possible.  It has poor performance, does not handle most edge cases, and no longer exists as of .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: What shall I use instead? NewtonSoft?

Comment: And your question is unclear since your resulting json is an array[object] vs an object, whereas your seeding dictionaries are both array[object].  How do you propose to merge the data in this way?

Comment: Newtonsoft, System.Text.Json, Jil, etc etc.  Any modern, supported serializer that handles dates is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get that exact format the only way would be to write a custom JsonConverter.

If you use NewtonSoft you will have two methods to override: ReadJson(...) and WriteJson(...), one is for serializing the other for deserializing.
That way you can write you own code responsible for serializing and deserializing.

In your case you can merge the two dictionaries into one and transform that into a Json string. When you deserialize that dictionary Json string, your custom code kicks in and you can do whatever you want.

Check NewtonSoft docs for this: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm